# How do I make the div blue box go in front of the h1 text?

Tags: html, css

I don't know how to make the div display in front of the h1 text, so that the blue box is in front of the text? I have been stuck on this for the past 30 mins and cant resolve it in my head. I am a beginner so please have patience.

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
    
.wrapper2 {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 2;
  width: 500px;
  height: 250px;
  background: blue;
}
    
h1 {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper2">
  <h1>Welcome</h1>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try this:

```css
.wrapper2 {
  width: 500px;
  height: 250px;
  background: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper2"></div>
<h1>Welcome</h1>
```

Although then it's not really a "wrapper" anymore, so maybe you'll need to create an element just for the blue square.

You've placed your `h1` inside the wrapper2, so you can try to move it after it if you want to style them separately. I would also suggest to not use `absolute` position unless you really want this, the consequences of doing this will quickly become apparent as you build out a larger page.

You can make each element "inline" rather than "block", this will make them follow the text flow of the page: `display: inline;`

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned above, you can simply put the `<h1>` element above your wrapper in HTML. If you want your `<h1>` to stay inside, you could use this:
`display: none;` or `visibility: hidden;` `opacity: 0;`

CSS:

```
h1 {
  position: relative;
  /* either of these */
  display: none;
  visibility: hidden;
  opacity: 0;
}
```